# Unable to run asp.net core project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Here is my launchsettings.json

```
{
 "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": false,
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:62868",
  "sslPort": 44324
}
},
 "profiles": {
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
"AspNetCoreApi": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
 }
}
}
```

WHen i run application i get error **An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.**

**Most likely causes:
system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true.**

IN IIS i tried to set Asp.Net Impersonation as Disabled for Default Website

Still no luck.

**Update1**

Here is my csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

 <PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="..\LoggerService\LoggerService.csproj" />
 </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

Comment: can you C&P your `csproj` contents? The reason I ask is i want to see what nuget packages you added. It looks like you may be mixing ASP.NET with ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @Andy i added csproj contents but i dont see anything fishy there

Comment: It's strange -- if I google your error, i see a lot of things dealing with ASP.NET, nothing with ASP.NET Core.

Comment: If you take the reference to `LoggerService.csproj` out, will it compile?

Comment: @Andy yes no issues. Actually i just added reference now. I anyway was getting this error before adding this reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by disabling Asp.Net Impresonation in IIS at root level

[image]